# IndexedDB - Is keyPath already an Index?

Tags: indexeddb

A quick question.

When you create an IndexedDB and specify a particular `keyPath`, do you still need to create and index with the same key?

I would assume that the `keyPath` is an index itself, but I don't know and haven't found any information about it.

Edit: Ok, to clarify, what I mean is, do you get the performance benefit on an Index with a keyPath?

Comment: Do you mean create an objectstore defined by a keypath? If this is what you mean, then it's not necessary to create an index on that key path and you can directly query the objectstore.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't technically create an index, but it's basically the same thing. Every object in the database is associated with a key. If you set a key path, then they key is whatever the key path evaluates to. Then you can query with for that key (e.g. `IDBObjectStore.get`), no index needed.

Indexes only come into play when you want to efficiently query your database for something besides the key.

So the answer to your question is no, you don't need to create an index with the same key.

Comment: Is it the same thing performance-wise? Because I can also create an index with the same key, but does it affect performance?

Comment: It would depend on the implementation, but the index would probably make it a bit slower. If anything the index would be slower for reading due to the added complexity. Indexes also make writing slower, because each write needs to update the index. Benchmark it if you're curious.